# Pulling out an object with multiple values and passing them through with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, object

I have an object that I am parsing through to pass along.

It looks like this:

```js
var inputDescriptions = {
  customText: {
    message: "this is a message",
    note: "this is a note"
  },
  tool: "wrench",
  garage: "two-door",
  "garage-color": "white",
  message: "message",
  "message-color": "white",
  note: "note"
};
```

At the end of the parsing, I want it to be an array of item and descriptions like so:

this is called "inputDescriptions"

```js
[{
  item: "tool",
  description: "wrench"
}, {
  item: "garage",
  description: "two-door"
}, {
  item: "garage-color",
  description: "white"
}, {
  item: "noteText",
  description: "this is a note"
}, {
  item: "messageText",
  description: "this is a message"
}, {
  item: "message",
  description: "message"
}, {
  item: "note",
  description: "note"
}]
```

I'm getting really thrown off by the one item that is an object with two properties.

Here is the function as I have it:

```js
const parseSelections = (inputDescriptions) => {
  return Object.keys(inputDescriptions).map((choiceId) => {
    const optionId = inputDescriptions[choiceId];
    const userSelectionInput = {
      choiceId,
      optionId,
    };
    return userSelectionInput;
  });
};

const selections = parseSelections(inputDescriptions);
```

It gets close but not quite there:

```html
[
{item: "tool", description: "wrench"}
{item: "garage", description: "two-door"}
{item: "garage-color", description: "white"}
{item: "customText", description: {message: "this is a message", note: "this is a note"}
{item: "message", description: "message"}
{item: "note", description: "note"}
]
```

I tried to use Object.assign to pull out the customText object and reassign, but I still couldn't get it to work. Maybe I need to make a new function to parse through again? I feel like I'm so close but the object is throwing me off. Does anyone have a better idea of a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `customText` property from the object and process it separately.

```js
let inputDescriptions = {
  customText: {
    message: "this is a message",
    note: "this is a note"
  },
  tool: "wrench",
  garage: "two-door",
  "garage-color": "white",
  message: "message",
  "message-color": "white",
  note: "note"
};


const parseSelections = (inputDescriptions) => {
  inputDescriptions = Object.assign({}, inputDescriptions); // clone object
  let customText = inputDescriptions.customText;
  delete inputDescriptions.customText;
  return Object.keys(inputDescriptions).map((choiceId) => {
    const optionId = inputDescriptions[choiceId];
    const userSelectionInput = {
      choiceId,
      optionId,
    };
    return userSelectionInput;
  }).concat(
    Object.entries(customText).map(([key, val]) => ({
      choiceId: `${key}Text`,
      optionId: val
    }))
  );
};

const selections = parseSelections(inputDescriptions);
console.log(selections);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your function recursively if the type of the input is an object :

```
if (typeof inputDescriptions[choiceId] === "object") {
  return parseSelections(inputDescriptions[choiceId]);
}
```

the function will return a nested array the you can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const inputDescriptions = {
  customText: {
    message: "this is a message",
    note: "this is a note"
  },
  tool: "wrench",
  garage: "two-door",
  "garage-color": "white",
  message: "message",
  "message-color": "white",
  note: "note"
};

const parseSelections = (inputDescriptions, suff) => {
  return Object.keys(inputDescriptions).map(choiceId => {
    if (typeof inputDescriptions[choiceId] === "object") {
      return parseSelections(inputDescriptions[choiceId], "Text");
    } else {
      const optionId = inputDescriptions[choiceId];
      const userSelectionInput = {
        [choiceId + suff]: choiceId,
        optionId
      };

      return userSelectionInput;
    }
  });
};

const selections = parseSelections(inputDescriptions, '').flat();

console.log(selections);
```

Comment: `customText.message` is supposed to have `choiceId: "messageText"`, not `choiceId: "message"`

Comment: @Barmar , oh, didn't see that, i updated the answer but it will look weired for deeply nested objects, can't guess how to add the suffix :/

Comment: he might not need arbitrary nesting, in my answer I just treat the `customText` property as a special case.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for the case where I don't want to specify `customText`

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend restructuring you data, to save you development time and headache later down the line. adding to this would be a nightmare. You could you an object loop and spread the keys, with the values, but I would recommend making a new Arr of objects like this. It will be much easier to work with and anyone else reading the data will have a much better understanding of the data. With this Structure, you can loop through the items and if you need to loop through the object on that item. Hope it saves some headache.

```
let items = [
  {
  item: "tool",
  description:"Wrench"
},
{
  item: "garage",
  description:"two-door",
  garageColor:"some color"
},
{
  item: "some item",
  description:"des"

},
{
  item: "tool two",
  description:"Wrench 2"
},
{
  item: "customText",
  message:"this is a message",
  note:"this is a note",
}

]
```

Comment: I think you're right. I edited the output to be similar to the above, based on how it is received down the line.